# How to handle intent:// on a webView URL?

Tags: android, webview

I'm currently developing an android app with a `webView`. On some `urls` I need to use the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method, which is pretty straight forward :

```
if(url.startsWith("something")){
//do something
return true;
}
```

**My problem:**

Some `URLS`, on google search for example, have the following `URL` scheme :

```
intent://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_cricket#Intent;scheme=http;package=org.wikipedia;S.browser_fallback_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.pt%2Fsearchurl%2Fr.html%23app%3Dorg.wikipedia%26pingbase%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.pt%2F%26url%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fen.m.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FTest_cricket;S.android.intent.extra.REFERRER_NAME=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.pt;launchFlags=0x8080000;end
```

I've tried using :

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

But I got an error:

```
10-15 15:18:15.546: W/System.err(29086): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=intent://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_cricket }
```

How should I handle this kind of `URL` scheme ?

---

**UPDATE:**

Following @CommonsWare comments, I've tried using `parseUri()` on `Intent` to create an `Intent object` from the `URL` and then try `startActivity()`, something like:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent().parseUri(url, Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

But I still get :

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_cricket flg=0x8080000 pkg=org.wikipedia (has extras) }
```

I may have got the instructions wrong or I'm simply unable to construct the `intent` as @CommonsWare specified. Any tips on how to construct the `Intent`?

Comment: Either catch the `ActivityNotFoundException` or use `PackageManager` and `resolveActivity()` to detect this situation before calling `startActivity()`. In this case, the `Uri` is to an app (Wikipedia), and if that app is not installed, the `Intent` will not resolve. You will need to present some sort of error message to the user indicating this fact.

Comment: @CommonsWare If tap on a link with `intent://...` on it some browsers  (Firefox, Chrome, Opera)  successfully open the application, is there a way to forward the uri to the default browser and let it handle it ?

Comment: The default browser isn't handling it -- the Wikipedia app is supposed to. Though, now that I think about it, `ACTION_VIEW` probably isn't the right answer. Use `parseUri()` on `Intent` to create an `Intent` object from the URL, then try `startActivity()` on that `Intent`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, It makes sense, let me give it a try. I'll let you know after.

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you please check the updated question ?

Comment: "If tap on a link with intent://... on it some browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Opera) successfully open the application" -- meaning that it is opening the Wikipedia app that you have installed? Or is it opening the Wikipedia Web site? If the latter, there is an `S.browser_fallback_url` in that URL that would appear to be a Web page to show if the Wikipedia app is not installed, though I am uncertain how to get at that value in the parsed `Intent`.

Comment: **"meaning that it is opening the Wikipedia app that you have installed?"**, Yes, if installed, it launches the app, otherwise, opens the url specified in `S.browser_fallback_url`.

Comment: "if installed, it launches the app" -- was it installed, when you were testing just now?

Comment: Yes, it was, I just said that because I've tested with and without the app  installed.

Comment: Then I am out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: @CommonsWare If you're out of ideas, imagine me :)) thank you very much!

Comment: @CommonsWare Would you mind giving me your opinion about the following solution ? http://pastebin.com/Yr1A910y

Comment: @PedroLobito: Try adding `BROWSABLE` category to the intent object you are creating -- this is what browsers actually do: `myIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);`  Looks like the Wikipedia app specifies this category in its intent filter: https://github.com/Tpt/Wikipedia/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @PedroLobito: I can't speak to whether that's a reliable regex or not. I like Mikhail's recommendation of adding `BROWSABLE`, though I'm surprised it is needed here.

Comment: @PedroLobito Interesting. I've just tried your code (the second version with `myIntent = new Intent().parseUri(url...`), and it just worked for me. What happens if you don't install your own `WebViewClient`, and trying to click on an `intent:` URL? This will trigger the default URL handler in WebView, which will also try to fire an intent.

Comment: I didn't thought about it...  I do need to implement a `WebViewClient` but I'm curious and I'll give it a try asap. Tks!

Comment: This answer is working perfectly!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35612860/5846135

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Structure of this intent url is described here https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents.

So we can handle it in internal WebView like this:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.startsWith("intent://")) {
        try {
            Context context = view.getContext();
            Intent intent = Intent.parseUri(url, Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME);

            if (intent != null) {
                view.stopLoading();

                PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
                ResolveInfo info = packageManager.resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
                if (info != null) {
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    String fallbackUrl = intent.getStringExtra("browser_fallback_url");
                    view.loadUrl(fallbackUrl);

                    // or call external broswer
//                    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(fallbackUrl));
//                    context.startActivity(browserIntent);
                }

                return true;
            }
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            if (GeneralData.DEBUG) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Can't resolve intent://", e);
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: perfect! Finally a solution

Comment: Note: `view.stopLoading();` is not necessary, since the URL does not begin loading until it is returned by this function and is consumed by returning true.

Comment: This can be used for showing Firebase Short Links ( for eg. Google Map Url) in the Android WebView .. Since from webview, intent won't trigger and webpage won't be shown.

Comment: Not works in Api 30. check this link to fix
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/package-visibility-in-android-11-cc857f221cd9

Answer (score 6):

## [Comrade's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34022490/797495) is the one to use.

---

The way I managed to solve this isn't *elegant* but it works.

First we check if the **url** `startsWith` with `intent://` and contains `scheme=http`, if so, we get the value right after **intent://**`everything until#` and pass it to `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`, if not, we `return false` (ignore click).
I've tested this solution with several results from google mobile search, such as,  **twitter**, **facebook**, **google maps** and **wikipedia** and it worked flawlessly.

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading( WebView view, String url) {
    if(url.startsWith("intent://") && url.contains("scheme=http")){
        url = Uri.decode(url);
        String bkpUrl = null;
        Pattern regexBkp = Pattern.compile("intent://(.*?)#");
        Matcher regexMatcherBkp = regexBkp.matcher(url);
        if (regexMatcherBkp.find()) {
            bkpUrl = regexMatcherBkp.group(1);
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://"+bkpUrl));
            startActivity(myIntent);
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
   }
return false;
}
```

---

If you've a better solution, I would like to hear it.
Thank you all for the support, specially [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware).

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to handle intent:// url

```
binding.webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
                
                if (url.startsWith("intent://")) {
                    val intent = Intent.parseUri(url, Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)
                    startActivity(intent)
                    return true
                }
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url)
            }
            .
            .
            .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on, you can use this to access the URL scheme instead of all the regex stuff.

`url.getScheme();`   or   `request.getUrl().getScheme();`