# Open android app from web page using javascript issue

Tags: javascript, android

I have created simple `javascript` function to open my app from device it is working fine in most of the android devices but i am having issue in some device.

Code to open app is :

```
window.location.replace("intent://myappname?id=" + token + "#Intent;scheme=myappscheme;package=myapppackage;S.browser_fallback_url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2;end")
```

I am having problem in Device : **"Lenovo Tab3 7" OS: 6.0 Android**

It is not opening even my app or any other application from chrome browser can any one please help where i am missing anything or it is known issue of chrome in this specific device

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android open intent:// protocol in WebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609107/android-open-intent-protocol-in-webview)

Comment: No i need to open it from javascript code.

Comment: @MehulMohan see the question description i need to be done in javascript only no android code here javascript only

Comment: @Brijesh Is this problem solved? in case, this problem is solved give me a tip for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location="intent://myappname?id=" + token + "#Intent;scheme=myappscheme;package=myapppackage;S.browser_fallback_url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2;end";
```

This may help you.

Comment: Please explain the difference.

Comment: It's really helpful for me, Thanks for saving my golden time.