# open instagram app to share story with javascript

Tags: javascript, android-intent, instagram

I'm trying to redirect users on my website to their instagram story page with an image to post. an example to this will be sharing a music from spotify to instagram, but the difference is that I want to use javascript to achieve it on web instead of having a native application.
I`ve tried using this method:

```
<a href="intent:#Intent;package=com.instagram.android;end;"> open instagram </a>
```

This opens the play store page for instagram, not the app itself.

this method also provides the same result:

```
window.location = "intent://instagram?#Intent;package=com.instagram.android;S.browser_fallback_url=https%3A%2F%2Fmywebsite.com%2;end";
```

I think I need to provide a **scheme** for it to work as said [here in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44655716/13246012), but can't find any schemes related to instagram on this purpose.
The whole purpose is to open user's instagram story page and give it an image using intent to share it.

Comment: Hi DevineDecrypter. Did you find a solution for it? I am facing a similar issue. Can you add solution here?