# Convert intent web url to Android Intent

Tags: flutter, android-intent, webview-flutter

I currently integrate a webview (webview_flutter: 2.0.4) in my application for a payment process.
Unfortunately, at some point the following url is launched:

```
intent://payment#Intent;action=ch.twint.action.TWINT_PAYMENT;scheme=twint;S.code=18223;S.startingOrigin=EXTERNAL_WEB_BROWSER;S.browser_fallback_url=;end
```

This URL should launch the "twint" application (Swiss payment solution)
Unfortunately it doesn't work so I'm trying to recreate the corresponding android intent (android_intent: 2.0.0) but I can't.

Can anyone help me or any other idea for a solution?

I also tried with the url_launcher extension but I don't think it's the right solution.

Comment: Any idea for my question ?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: have you solved it??

Comment: Not yet... I'm going through the web portal for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you can execute native kotlin/java code when using flutter, but this can be solved (natively) by using the following code (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/35612860):

```kotlin
override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String): Boolean {

        if (url.startsWith("intent://")) {
            val intent = Intent.parseUri(url, Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME);
            return if (intent.resolveActivity(context.packageManager) != null) {
                context.startActivity(intent)
                true
            } else {
                // handle error, e.g. open playstore
                true
            }
        }
        /* 
          Rest of override url handling
          ...
        */
    }
```

On Android API 30+ `intent.resolveActivity`will only detect the installed twint app if you have the following entry in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="ch.twint.action.TWINT_PAYMENT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="twint" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Comment: I will try your solution ASAP. It's effectively possible to execute native android code in flutter.

Comment: Hi @alexdess, does this solution work if you have several twint apps installed? Like CreditSuisse Twint, BVC Twint, etc. Does it open the android native popup to select the app you want to pay with?

Comment: @EstebanChornet - also wondering the same. In this situation, iOS has an advantage in that the specific app desired is embedded in the link to the app. It seems Android only identifies it by the "action" name, which is always ch.twint.action.TWINT_PAYMENT - perhaps there is an additional "extra" key value pair you could send to specify the app? I've found no TWINT documentation around this.