# React native expo open url android web intent

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-native-web

How can I open an installed Android app from a url like `'intent://payment#Intent;action=ch.twint.action.TWINT_PAYMENT;scheme=twint;S.code={token};S.startingOrigin=EXTERNAL_WEB_BROWSER;S.browser_fallback_url=;end'`?

Everytime I try `Linking.openUrl()` from `expo-linking` through the Expo Go client I get a console error.
If I open it from the browser, it works fine.

EDIT:

I saw this SO, which is basically what I need to do, but he's using flutter, and since I'm using Expo, I cannot add specific code.

[Convert intent web url to Android Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67461868/convert-intent-web-url-to-android-intent)

I've seen `Expo Linking` has `sendIntent()` https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/linking/#linkingsendintentaction-extras method, but I don't know how to convert this kind of URL to pass it to the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved easily by using https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/intent-launcher/#intentlauncherstartactivityasyncactivityaction-params