# Android Studio Webview open link directly on Google Play

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, google-play

I have a Web App that loads locally html.

In one html, I have a link to a Google Play app, but the link opens inside the app, inside the webview.

On iOS devices any link https://itunes.apple.com/app/id000 will automatically open iTunes/App Store on the devices.

Is there a way to open the Google Play app directly from an html?

I'm trying _blank or the market:// as suggested on other questions, but nothing works.

```
<a href="http://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.earth" target="_blank">App Link</a>

<a href="market://details?id=com.google.earth" target="_top">App Link 2</a>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to parse the URL yourself in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151246/how-to-handle-intent-on-a-webview-url

Comment: Could you please be more specific? shouldOverrideUrlLoading should be used to parse "http://market.android.com/details?" into "market://"? That's it?

Comment: Parse it both ways, if it starts with 'market://' or is a matching URI 'play.google.com' fire an intent to launch google play app. See: http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html

Answer (score 2):

you can use this it will work

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (Uri.parse(url).getScheme().equals("market")) {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            Activity host = (Activity) view.getContext();
            host.startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            // Google Play app is not installed, you may want to open the app store link
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            view.loadUrl("http://play.google.com/store/apps/" + uri.getHost() + "?" + uri.getQuery());
            return false;
        }

    }
    return false;
}});
```

maybe  this will help any one