# Open android app from webView inside another android app

Tags: android, android-intent, webview

In my app there is a WebView to which I load a website from server. 
There are two cases:

1. On the loaded website there is a button which should lead to an another app. I know it can be handled like [this](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents):

   ```
   <a href = "intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=zxing;package=com.google.zxing.client.android;end"> Click me </a>
   ```

but this doesn't work in the WebView (only in a standalone browser)! I tried to handle it in shouldOverrideUrlLoading and redirect to an external browser with Intent, but the URI with "intent://" URL is not recognised and cannot be opened.

2. The link I get from server is the 'intent' link.

The behaviour in both cases should be the same: if app is installed open the app, if not open Google Play do download the app.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151246/how-to-handle-intent-on-a-webview-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best option, but I handeled it similarily to what @vineetv suggested. This method is called inside `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`:

```
private void handleNewUrl(String url) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);

    if (uri.getScheme().equals("http") || uri.getScheme().equals("https"))
        openExternalWebsite(url);
    else if (uri.getScheme().equals("intent")) {
        String appPackage = getAppPackageFromUri(uri);

        if (appPackage != null) {
            PackageManager manager = getContext().getPackageManager();
            Intent appIntent = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(appPackage);

            if (appIntent != null) {
                getActivity().startActivity(appIntent);
            } else {
                openExternalWebsite("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackage);
            }
        }
    }
}

private String getAppPackageFromUri(Uri intentUri) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("package=(.*?);");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(intentUri.getFragment());

    if (matcher.find())
        return matcher.group(1);

    return null;
}

private void openExternalWebsite(String url) {
    Intent webeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    webeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    webeIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    getActivity().startActivity(webeIntent);
}
```

It seems, to work. But if you have a better solution, let me know!