# err_unknown_url_scheme in Android WebView

Tags: java, php, android, html, webview

I have a WebView display page, and when I click on one buttons it will redrect in another web site or open in some app such as telegram but this error appears: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

I kindly ask you for some advice as I have tried several suggestions but without results
I'm a amateur.

This is my code

```
 package com.allcodingtutorial.mywebactivity;
 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.graphics.Bitmap;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
 import android.webkit.WebSettings;
 import android.webkit.WebView;
 import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 WebView webView;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("https://vnexpress.net/");
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
}

public static class MywebClient extends WebViewClient{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
    }
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(webView.isFocused() && webView.canGoBack())
    {
        webView.goBack();
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Well what is that unknown scheme?

Answer (score 0):

inside the shouldOverrideUrlLoading function you can call a function and check for the url scheme and based on that scheme you can handle whether you want to call an external app/activity or let the url be loaded inside the webview. you can refer to these links -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/43872730/8879652 https://stackoverflow.com/a/34022490/8879652

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).